# What are the equivalence classes of $\mathbb{Z}$ under the associate relation?

Tags: ring-theory

Two elements a,b are associates if a|b and b|a.

So far, my thought process is the following:
for $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$, if b > a then a may divide b but clearly b cannot divide a since it's larger. So wouldn't there be one equivalence class for each integer, consisting of just that integer?

Comment: Negative numbers to be taken into account

Comment: What are the units?

Comment: It's not relevant for this problem, but also keep in mind that every integer $x$ satisfies $x \mid 0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For two integers $a$ and $b$ , we have $ a|b$ and $ b|a$ if and only if $a=\pm b$

Thus each equivalence class is  a set  {$\pm a$}.

{$0$} ,{$\pm 1$}, {$\pm 2$}, {$\pm 3$}, {$\pm 4$},.....